# HTML fetched using an ajax service call is getting distorted for some time before js and css gets applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am making a service call using ajax and loading an HTML content on my page. **This HTML has got content, some external script calls and css inside it**. But when this HTML gets loaded, it gets distorted for a while (3-4 sec) and then js and css gets applied which are inside that HTML. Is there any solution where I can get the HTML with js and css applied and then append it in my div or wherever I want to put it.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',    
                url: service-URL,
                crossDomain : _crossDomain,
                contentType : 'text/plain',
                data:JSON.stringify(objReq),
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                },
                success: function(outputHTML){
                    $("#contentDiv").html(outputHTML);
                }
            });
```

Comment: try `$("#contentDiv").empty().html(outputHTML);`

Comment: try [require.js](http://requirejs.org) to load dependencies or load them on initial page load.

Comment: .empty() will just empty the content of that div. How its gonna help render the HTML with js and css applied.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 how do I configure require js to load external js calls from HTML which I am fetching from service.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid this simply you can load css and javascripts in your main document.

in any case and for any reason if you dont want to load them before ajax call in main document( for example to boost up first page loading) you can use 
nested ajax call like this :

```
   $.get(resource.url, {cache:true}, function(css) {
   //cache : true will handle browser cache , it will load instantly:  

       $("head").append($("<link>",{
          rel: "stylesheet",
          type: "text/css",
          href: resource.url
       }));

   }).then(function(){
      //You can now call your AJAX here
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

When using `html()` or `innerHTML=` you are writing only the code into your site. The interpreter then has to understand that afterwards, which causes a delay.
What you can do instead, is apply the content as DOM already, by either not passing it as text/plain, or by creating a documentFragment first `document.createDocumentFragment()` , which is like an empty Node you can append child nodes to, and afterwards append this fragment to the main DOM.

Comment: You can't set the innerHTML of a document fragment like you would do with a normal node, that's the problem.

Comment: @ps007 but you can parse it into DOM before.

Comment: I was able to append the response i.e. document . But problem was fetching the response and putting it into target div

Comment: @ps007 why dont you try to recieve the content as html? Have you tried preloading css and scripts, as milad suggested?

Comment: @ps007 you shoud wait for the scripts and css to load. Add that to milad's solution, it should help. I think, you can do that with `onlaod` but better look it up before.